# How do I properly append a Python list with data from one data frame column based on criteria for values in another column?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop, lookup

I have the following code below that is supposed to append a list (result_value) with values times 1000 from one data frame column when values in another column for each row meet criteria:

```
# result_value
result_value = []
detection_limit_unit = []

for unit in data.UNITS:
    if unit == 'mg/kg':
        detection_limit_unit.append('ug/kg')
    else:
        detection_limit_unit.append(unit)
        
for Result in data.Result:
    for unit in data.UNITS:
        if data.UNITS.any() == 'mg/kg':
            result_value.append(Result*1000)
        else:
            result_value.append(RL)
```

The upper for loop works properly but the lower one appends result_value with far too many values. How should I edit the code to populate the list with the proper number of values?

The data are as follows:

| LABSAMPID | Result | UNITS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P222264-03 | ND | ug/L |
| P222264-01 | 180 | ug/L |
| P222126-02 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-02 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-02 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-02 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-02 | 0.18 | mg/kg |
| P222126-03 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222264-03 | 10 | ug/L |
| P222264-03 | 150 | ug/L |
| P222126-03 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-03 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-03 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-03 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-03 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-03 | 0.195 | mg/kg |
| P222126-02 | ND | mg/kg |
| P222126-02 | ND | mg/kg |

Answer (score 1):

You should use `np.where` to do your computations in a vectorised manner:

```py
detection_limit_unit = list(np.where(data.UNITS == 'mg/kg', 'ug/kg', data.UNITS))
# ['ug/L', 'ug/L', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/L', 'ug/L', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg', 'ug/kg']
result_value = list(np.where(data['Result'] == 'ND', 'ND', pd.to_numeric(data['Result'], errors='coerce') * np.where((data['UNITS']=='mg/kg'), 1000, 1)))
# ['ND', '180.0', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', '180.0', 'ND', '10.0', '150.0', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', 'ND', '195.0', 'ND', 'ND']
```

Comment: Note if you're writing the data to a new column in your dataframe you don't need to convert it to a list first, just assign the result of `np.where` directly e.g. `data['Scaled'] = np.where(...)`